# How do I populate a ListFragment in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, android-fragments

I have seen all kinds of tutorials about how to turn an Activity into a ListActivity to populate a ListView, but nothing for ListFragments. I have two tabs with a Fragment under each. Here is what my fragment currently looks like.... can someone give me some idea on how I can do this?

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment {    

String[] items = { "12 Monkeys", "(500) Days of Summer", "Chariots of Fire" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){      
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 }
}
```

and here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to get `items` to show in the ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to inflate a `view` containing a `listview` inside of your `ListFragment`. Simply create an `adapter`, give it some data and in `onCreate()` of your `fragment` call `setListAdapter()`. Then somewhere else (presumably in your `Activity`) you can then add this `fragment` with a `fragmentmanager`.